# React route to a specific product details page from a product page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a product page, where if the user clicks on a specific product card, it will redirect the user to a new page where that specific product details will be displayed only. However, in my code, even after redirecting it to the details page, it still shows the entire product list on that page. I need a bit of help to solve this issue. I have tried passing props to differentiate. But it doesn't seem to work.
My FeaturedProduct.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductDetails from "./ProductDetails";
import axios from "axios";

function FeaturedProduct(props) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  function fetchProducts() {
    axios
      .get("https://shoppingapiacme.herokuapp.com/shopping") 
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res); 
        setProducts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Your Products List is shown below:</h1>
      <div className="item-container">
       
        {products.map((product) => (
          <div className="card" key={product.id}>
            {" "}
           
            <h3>{product.item}</h3>
            <p>
              {product.city}, {product.state}
            </p>
            <Router>
              <Link to="/productdetails">More Details</Link>

              <Switch>
                <Route path="/productdetails">
                <ProductDetails product={product}/>
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FeaturedProduct;
```

My ProductDetails.js:

```
function ProductDetails(props) {
const {name, color} = props.product;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <h1>{color}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default  ProductDetails;
```

My App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import FeaturedProduct from "./FeaturedProduct";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FeaturedProduct />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: <Link to="/productdetails">More Details</Link> how do you utilize the product id exactly ? the convention is to pass the id to params and then render that specific product with specific product id so structure your link as something like: to='/product/:id' and then pull the id from params and fetch single product within that single product page

Comment: So instead of <Link to="/productdetails">More Details</Link> I should do <Link to='/product/:id' >More Details</Link> ??

Comment: It does not work. I have been trying to find a way to use the productid somewhere, but I am a beginner and I am having a hard time

Comment: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params take a look at this. Also, you can't structure your router setup (router(switch...)) within that  component. setup your router within app.js

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are rendering that same router/link/route for each mapped product element.

```
<Router>
  <Link to="/productdetails">More Details</Link>

  <Switch>
    <Route path="/productdetails">
      <ProductDetails product={product}/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

This means when the path is "/productdetails" you render a `Route` and `ProductDetails` component for each and every one of them.

## A Solution

It is more common to render one single `Router` and `Route` for a product details page with either a specific product `id` as a route param or to pass entire product object in route state (*though less common*).

Move the `Router` into `App` to provide a single routing context to the app:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <FeaturedProduct />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Move the `Switch` and `Route` below the `products` mapping, leaving only the `Link` in the map callback. Link to a specific product `id` and use the `Route`'s `render` prop to search for the matching product by `id` to pass in as a prop:

```
function FeaturedProduct(props) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  function fetchProducts() {
    axios
      .get("https://shoppingapiacme.herokuapp.com/shopping")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setProducts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Your Products List is shown below:</h1>
      <div className="item-container">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <div className="card" key={product.id}>
            <h3>{product.item}</h3>
            <p>
              {product.city}, {product.state}
            </p>
            <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>More Details</Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/product/:id"
          render={({ match }) => (
            <ProductDetails
              product={products.find(
                (product) => String(product.id) === match.params.id
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-route-to-a-specific-product-details-page-from-a-product-page]